# can't access submenu link using mouseover

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to access submenu link "WHAT IS Flex?" under "About Flex" from

http://flex.apache.org/ using selenium Web Driver.

Whenever a mouseover is performed submenu is highlighted and disappears before i can access submenu.

*Imported a few unnecessary packages.Please don't mind.
Code:

```
package com.ram.workingtitle;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;  
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class Mouseover {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("http://flex.apache.org/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);        

        /*
        Used Firepath for generating xpath
        */
        WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/li[2]/a"));
        WebElement sub=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a"));

        Actions action=new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        action.moveToElement(sub).build().perform();

        System.out.println("executed");
    }
}
```

Please help.

Thanks&Regards,
Ram.

Comment: Please format the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   Actions action = new Actions(webDriver); 
            action.moveToElement(webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav']/li[2]/a")))
            .build()
            .perform();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav']/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
```

Note: Thread.sleep is not a good practice. Just use implicit wait in your program or/and WebDriverWait.

Comment: It is always better to wait till DOM gets ready otherwise such issues will always pop up. Vote up if the answer is useful. :-)